# Probability variance equation

Tags: probability

I Have this function where $k$ is a conctant:

[image]

I need to find $V(6-8X)$.

So I understood the equation is $V(6)+V(8x) = 64V(x)$.
Then I solved for k, $4k+16k+36k+1/18+1/18+2/2 = 1$, and I got $k=1/144$ (Which I not sure if I do like I did or just add the functions without putting the x's in).
What I don't understand is how to solve for $x$ now. just to place $k$ and to sum up for $x$?

Comment: Once you know $k$, you need to calculate the variance of $X$, then multiply it by 64 to get the final answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perhaps best to set up a table for problems like these.
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc} 
x & \Pr[X = x] & x \Pr[X = x] & x^2 \Pr[X = x] \\
\hline
 1 & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & 4 k & 8 k & 16 k \\
 3 & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 4 & 16 k & 64 k & 256 k \\
 5 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{25}{2} \\
 6 & 36 k & 216 k & 1296 k \\
\end{array}
$$
From the requirement that the second column adds to $1$, we obtain $k = 1/144$, hence the table becomes
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc} 
x & \Pr[X = x] & x \Pr[X = x] & x^2 \Pr[X = x] \\
\hline
 1 & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{18} \\
 2 & \frac{1}{36} & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{9} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{18} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{2} \\
 4 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{16}{9} \\
 5 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{25}{2} \\
 6 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{2} & 9 \\
\end{array}
$$
Then we compute $\operatorname{E}[X]$ as the total of the third column, and $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ as the total of the fourth column.  Then the variance is $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \frac{533}{324}.$$  Then $$\operatorname{Var}[6-8X] = \operatorname{Var}[8X] = 64 \operatorname{Var}[X].$$  The $6$ drops out because variance is invariant to location shifts; the negative sign drops out because variance is invariant to reflection.  Or more formally, you can write $$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}[6-8X] 
&= \operatorname{E}[(6-8X-\operatorname{E}[6-8X])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(6-8X-(6-8\operatorname{E}[X]))^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(-8X+8\operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[64(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= 64 \operatorname{Var}[X].
\end{align*}$$